# Is the sentence “I live in a village which is located in the south “ active or passive?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice, reduced-relative-clauses

I need to know in order to know how to rewrite the sentence using reduced relative clauses

Comment: "... a village [which is] located in the south". The words inside the brackets can be omitted.  The  question doesn't really touch on the passive.

Comment: "Located" is an adjective in your example, so the question of active vs passive does not arise.

Comment: "I live in a southern village."

Answer (score 0):

To talk of active or passive here is not really meaningful.

The sentence does not have any transitive verbs, so it can't really be passivized.

---

If you say "A village is lived in by me", that's a possible passive sentence, but it feels extremely unusual due to the fact that the agentive *by* clause in a passive sentence can only take agents that are more salient than the passive sentence's true subject. That is, *me* would be **very emphatic**, as though to say, "the village is lived in by me *and nobody else*". And, therefore, *village* would conversely be less salient and more likely to have a definite article.

Comment: Crucially, "located" is an adjective here, not a verb.

Comment: Heh, how about "A village is lived in by me!"

Comment: @AndyBonner that sentence feels extremely weird to me; I have added a note explaining why